# build perl one-liners from short perl script and combines in to other line

Tags: perl

Continue my previous question (but other queastion),

According to the following perl script (rename.pl)

how to build perl one-liners  line from the rename.pl script
in order to replace the: /var/tmp/rename.pl (from find command ...)
with the one-liners perl syntax?

(I dont want to use the rename.pl script ,)

```
   find  /  -name "$OLD_HOST"  -print0 | xargs -0 /var/tmp/rename.pl 'print "changing $_\n"; s/$OLD_HOST/host_10/g'
```

rename.pl script:

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl

   $op = shift;
     for (@ARGV) {
      $was = $_;
      eval $op;
      die $@ if $@;
      rename($was,$_) unless $was eq $_;
    }
```

Comment: I use the [full-size version](http://training.perl.com/scripts/rename) of the rename script everyday.  Why in the world would you *not* want to use existing code?

Comment: please give example for the following: , I need to scan all files and dirs under / directory and want to rename host1 with host_10 how to do that with your perl script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the bullet-proofed, debugged `rename.pl` script?

```
find ... |
xargs -0 perl -e 'my $op - shift; foreach (@ARGV)
                  { my $was = $_; eval $op; die $@ if $@;
                    rename($was, $_) unless $was eq $_; }' \
              s/x/y/g
```

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner will find zip files with numbers inside the filename, and print some "mv" shell commands rather than executing them immediately. You can paste this into the command line for more control later.
Maybe this will get you started.

> find . -name "*.zip"  | perl -nE
>   'chomp; my $f = qq($_); $f =~ /(\d+)/;
>   say "mv $f " . sprintf("%03d", $1) . ".zip";'